# Get image in activity through "Share" button in gallery | Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to add my application to share list when I click to **"Share"** button on some image in gallery (for instance) and then I want to get this image in ImageView.

[Share List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpMAT.png)

Thanks for help!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#receiving-data-activity

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir thank you! This link is really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent filters inform the Android system what intents your application is willing to accept.

For images, you’d add the following to your  `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

When the gallery application tries to share an image by constructing an intent and passing it to startActivity(), your application will be listed as an option in the Android Sharesheet or intent resolver. Upon selecting your app, the corresponding activity (.ui.MyActivity in the example above) will be started. It is then up to you to handle the content appropriately within your code and UI.

[More info here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)

Answer (score 0):

you can check [following link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html)  here it was mentioned exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: It's for share inside my app, but I want to get some photo from another app to mine